# Was the bug bounty ever claimed for OP_CTV?

Tags: security, history, bip119-checktemplateverify

There was a large bug bounty on the implementation of OP_CTV in 2022 (according to this [source](https://bipbounty.org/bounties/1e101655-bad8-5147-82f7-f03145d567af) it reached as much as 5.3 Bitcoin). Was it ever claimed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it was never claimed. However, a bug was found in the implementation of OP_CTV in September 2022. This was 5 months after the client attempting to activate OP_CTV was slated for release (April 2022). From the "7 Theses on a next step for BIP-119" [blog post](https://rubin.io/bitcoin/2022/04/17/next-steps-bip119/) dated April 17th 2022:

> This post starts with a conclusion:
>
> Within a week from today, you’ll find software builds for a CTV Bitcoin Client for all platforms linked here:
>
> Mac OSX TODO:
> Windows TODO:
> Linux TODO:
> These will be built using GUIX, which are reproducible for verification. The intended code to be built will be https://github.com/JeremyRubin/bitcoin/tree/checktemplateverify-v23.0rc5-paramsv0 which is based on Bitcoin Core v23.0 release candidate 5, with commit hash dd9a4e0ea8a109d1607ca1ec16119b1bc952d8b0. You can begin testing this immediately, and even producing your own GUIX builds as well.
>
> Signatures for the builds will be available below:
>
> TODO: … .asc
> The source tarball:
>
> TODO: … .tar.gz
> The client has a Speedy Trial release similar to Taproots with parameters proposed to be:
>
> Signal Start MTP: 1651708800 (May 5th, 2022, 00:00 UTC)
> Signal Timeout MTP: 1660262400 (August 12th, 2022, 00:00 UTC)
> Activation Height: 762048 (Approximately Nov 9th)
> See the appendix to verify these parameters.
>
> This ensures 6 signalling periods to activate CTV. The Start and Timeout are targeting mid-period (if hashrate stays steady) times to ensure that it is unlikely we would have more or fewer periods.
>
> The week delay between this post and builds is to provide time for review on the selection of parameters as well as ability to rebase onto a final v23.0 release, should it become ready within the week. Backports are in the works for v22.0, but release builds may not be made available as Bitcoin’s release build processes have changed since v22.0 to use GUIX. The branch for backports is available here: https://github.com/JeremyRubin/bitcoin/tree/checktemplateverify-v22.0 with current commit hash 4d2c39314834a28cd46da943a12300cca8ffcb10, if you would like to help with testing.

On September 23rd 2022 AJ Towns [posted](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21702#discussion_r978357483) on the Bitcoin Core OP_CTV [pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21702):

> Shouldn't this be:
>
> m_bip119_c_s = (f != nullptr ? f : single_threaded);
>
> or something? Otherwise nothing seems to be done with the `bip_119_cache_synchronizer_t f` that was passed in other than sometimes asserting that it's nullptr.

Jeremy Rubin later [responded](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21702#discussion_r979273387):

> Very good catch, I think this should be eligible for the bipbounty.org bounty as a Major?

A Major reward was defined on [bipbounty.com](https://bipbounty.org/bounties/1e101655-bad8-5147-82f7-f03145d567af/) as "Something that ought to be fixed before release of CTV. Does not require changes to the BIP" and was entitled to a 0.1 BTC - 0.25 BTC payout. I'm personally unsure whether it was claimed or not.